# <input> has mysterious bottom padding

Tags: html, css, forms, webkit

I am trying to do some quite precise styling on some form elements, and this issue is causing me a lot of grief.

If I try to remove `padding`, `margin`, `border` and `outline` from an `<input>` (with `display: block`) so that the size of the field is purely determined by the text, the input field ends up having a few pixels extra padding than any other block level element styled exactly the same way. Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/b9zfa/

```
<input class="normalised testSubject" value="hello" />
<div class="normalised testSubject">hello</div>
```

Rendering:

[image: Rendering]

In that example, the `<div>` gets a computed height of `16px` while the `<input>` gets a computed height of `19px`.

I get the same behaviour in Chrome 16, Firefox 9 and Opera 11 so it's clearly rendering engine independent.

I can fix the issue by manually adding a height, but I don't want to do that because I want the design to remain [responsive](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here, and how I can reliably make sure that the `<input>` will be the same height as any block level element that follows it?

Comment: remove `line-height : 1em` from `.normalised` CSS to make them of same height. This would make `div` as same height as your `input` field. See this modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uday99/b9zfa/4/)

Comment: @Dave: I have confirmed that with Chrome 17.

Comment: Anyone running into this problem should voice their support of these two bug reports https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349259 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697451

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `<input>` has a minimum `line-height` based on font size. Setting both elements to a larger `line-height` value works, as does removing `line-height` altogether. But that still doesn't allow you to have smaller heights than the minimum. The fix for that is using the `first-line` pseudo-element and setting it to `display: inline-block;`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/B7cmQ/

[image]

CSS:

```css
.normalised:first-line {
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

But this doesn't explain why the `<input>` is acting differently than the `<div>`. Even `-webkit-appearance: none;` didn't fix it. It would seem there is some invisible voodoo on inputs that treats its contents as `inline`. `inline` elements have minimun `line-height` based on font size, which is the behavior we're seeing here. That's why `first-line` fixes it. It seems to be styling the "child" element of the `<input>`.

Here's a demo that shows the minimum `line-height` on `inline` elements. The `<div>` element honors `line-height: 7px;`. The `<span>`, even though its computed value is showing `7px;`, is not honoring it visually.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/zhReb/

Output:

[image]

HTML:

```html
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="div-large">div <br />large</div> 
</div> 
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="div-medium">div <br />med</div> 
</div> 
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="div-small">div <br />small</div> 
</div> 
<div id="container"> 
    <span id="span-large">span <br />large</span> 
</div> 
<div id="container"> 
    <span id="span-medium">span <br />med</span> 
</div> 
<div id="container"> 
    <span id="span-small">span <br />small</span> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#container { 
    background-color: lightblue;   
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 200px; 
    vertical-align: top; 
}

#div-large { 
    line-height: 50px; 
} 

#div-medium { 
    line-height: 20px; 
} 

#div-small { 
    line-height: 7px; 
}

#span-large { 
    line-height: 50px; 
    vertical-align: top; 
} 

#span-medium {
    line-height: 20px; 
    vertical-align: top; 
} 

#span-small {
    line-height: 7px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation, thank you. I haven't fully tested your :first-child solution cross-browser, but it looks quite promising. I'm wondering if this behaviour maybe only exists in browsers that support the HTML5 "placeholder"? I suppose the rendering engines create an element inside form fields to help manipulate the content somehow. Anyway, this is the answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: @RobinWinslow IE7+ and all other browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17

Comment: not what I meant. I meant that the fix of making the `:first-line` `inner-block` would work cross-browser. But it probably will.

Comment: This fix doesn't work in Firefox for setting `line-height` smaller than `normal` (around 1-1.2em). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981420/how-can-i-remove-the-extra-and-different-pseudo-padding-on-text-inputs-in-webki

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `line-height` seems to solve the problem.

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mreq/b9zfa/5/). Tested only in FF tho.

Comment: There is no `line-height:medium`, it's working because you've effectively removed the line-height by passing an invalid value. Why removing the line-height works, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Instead of removing the line-height, making sure to have `line-height: normal` works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they're using the exact same font (including size)?

Try adding `box-sizing: border-box` to the `input`.

I've never had this issue myself, but I've only used it as a test somewhere in IE9...

Comment: Form elements are `border-box` by default, he is resetting them to be consistent with `content-box` on other elements.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm months late to this question, but I ran across it in a Google search and wanted to add one thing that might help clarify some of the other answers with regard to the `<input>` elements in Firefox.

The default form styling in Firefox includes some awkward CSS:

```
input {
   ...
   line-height: normal !important;
   ...
}
```

This makes it effectively impossible to override the `line-height` property of any form input in Firefox. The problem has existed for years, and while it seems like a no-brainer for the FF devs to remove the `!important` from the rule, I gather there are some under-the-hood implementation problems with doing so. Also, apparently there are some websites (including YouTube) that ***rely*** on the behavior of this rule.

For details and lots of discussion see [Mozilla bug #349259](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349259). There's also a good blog post on this at [456bereastreet.com](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201108/line-height_in_input_fields/), and another (older) by Eric Meyer at [meyerweb.com](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/).