# How can I remove the extra, and different pseudo-padding on text inputs in Webkit and Gecko?

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit

The problem only happens on `input[type="text"]` in Webkit. No matter what I do, there is the equivalent of an extra `padding: 1px 0 0 1px` (top and left only) on the element.

A similar problem happens in Gecko, `input[type="text"]` has an equivalent extra `padding: 1px 0 0 1px` and `input[type="button"]` has an extra `padding: 1px 0 0 0`.

Here's a JSFiddle showing you everything I've tried, and nothing works: http://jsfiddle.net/PncMR/10/

Interestingly, when you set the line-height of all the elements to `0` ( http://jsfiddle.net/PncMR/11/ ), the only unaffected elements are the ones with the problems,  so I'm assuming that the browser is defaulting to a specific line-height, and I'm now looking for a way to override it.

---

I've found nothing in the webkit base styles that would do this, but feel free to check yourself:

http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

This is not a `moz-focus-inner` problem, or an `appearance: none` problem, or a `box-sizing` problem, or an `outline` problem and I can't find any other solutions.

---

Edit: See my answer below for the vertical padding problems, but **I'm still looking for a solution to the extra `padding-left: 1px` equivalent on text-inputs only in webkit and gecko.** ( http://jsfiddle.net/PncMR/14/ )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### In Webkit

The extra vertical "padding" on `input[type="text"]` in Webkit is because you cannot give text inputs a `line-height` value of less than `normal`, which isn't a specific value, [but varies depending on the typeface](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/).

I know this is the cause, but I cannot find where the input would be getting this style, because it doesn't appear in the Webkit UA stylesheets.

### In Gecko

The extra vertical "padding" on `input[type="text"]` and `input[type="button"]` in Gecko is due to user-agent stylesheet containing:

```
input {
    line-height: normal !important;
}
```

and `!important` declarations in the user-agent stylesheet [cannot be overidden in any way](http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/).

### Conclusion

You can't go under `line-height: normal` in Webkit, and you can't have anything other than `line-height: normal` on these elements in Gecko, so the best solution is to always style these elements with `line-height: normal` to get the best consistency, which isn't really a nice solution. Ideally, we'd be able to override all UA styles.

---

Neither of these account for the extra 1px of what acts like `text-indent` that only appears on `input[type="text"]` in both rendering engines.

---

People who care about this, should voice their opinions on these two Bugzilla threads:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697451
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349259

Comment: The UA stylesheet is applied first, right? You can override `!important` with another `!important`. The one that comes last (assuming same specificity), takes precedence.

Comment: One would think, but that second article I linked did research and found this not to be the case no matter how hard he tried. UA !importants must have a special case. 

The bug threads I added vouch for this as well.

Comment: Both those bugs are marked as fixed, as of Firefox 30.

Comment: This was essential in helping me fix matching `line-height` between two elements (one of which was an `<input type="text">`and the other a `<span>`) in Chrome 75.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this is happening is because the browser is treating the content of the `<input>` as if it were an inline element, regardless of the `display` setting of the `<input>`. Inline elements have a minimum height as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/zhReb/

You can override this behavior by making the "child" element `inline-block`. You can do this with the `first-line` pseudo-element.

```
input:first-line {
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

I go into more detail as to why this is in my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8964378/918414

This doesn't work in Firefox, but for another reason: Firefox's UA stylesheet (as outlined in @Ian's answer).

Comment: Just verified, this does work in Webkit, but unfortunately not in Firefox.

Comment: This worked for me in Webkit. Anyone find a fix for Firefox yet?