# Chrome input padding issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input

I'm having an issue with inconsistency with inputs in chrome.

I'm using a big font-size, but setting the height and line-height to smaller to remove gaps above and below the text.

```
input {
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

IE and Firefox seem to render it correctly, but chrome seems to add padding to the text of the input.

Fiddle showing what's going on here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomdickie/nZY8r/1/

EDIT:

To add a bit more clarity, to this here are some screenshots:

Firefox

[image]

Chrome

[image]

I'm trying to get Chrome to behave like Firefox (and IE) do.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981420/how-can-i-remove-the-extra-and-different-pseudo-padding-on-text-inputs-in-webki

Comment: What version of chrome do you have???

Answer (score -1):

try this and its woring [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ap5sf/)

**HTML** code

```
<input type="text" name="uname" value="223" />
```

and **CSS** code is

```
input {
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /*height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;*/
}
```

I've tested this code.

Comment: "to remove gaps above and below the text". The pseudo padding still remains