# Input bigger than it should be

Tags: html, css

Hello my fellow CSS enthusiasts. It's not usual that I can not answer a CSS question.

The bug happens in Chrome and IE11, Firefox renders it the same size but different clipping.

I have an inputfield and a div filled with text, they should have the same height and should scale with the parent font-size. The problem is that the inputfield is bigger than expected.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lg70qc4/

The `div` behaves like I expected, its height is `font-size` + `padding` * 2, but the inputfield is bigger than that.

I can not set the height as `em` since the padding is fix, but the font-size is not.

Why is the `input` bigger than the `div`?

Comment: Are you are referring to wanting the green rectangles to be the same size?

Comment: Both should be the same height, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `:first-line` pseudo element for input to make your both elements same height.

```
input:first-line {
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964281/input-has-mysterious-bottom-padding) you can find more information why it works.

Comment: No, if you inspect the element from `Chrome` or `Firefox` you would find that the `input` is still `67px` height and not `58px` as it should be

Comment: marian0 Thank you very much, but that's a really weird behavior.

@Enumy if you apply the property both are 90px height in total (content-box 58px
)

Comment: @Itrulia this isn't the problem, the problem consists of the `line-height` try set it to initial value and you would notice that the `input` wasn't affected by it `Which is also a problem with inputs in both chrome and firefox`.

Comment: Uhm it is fixed with that: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lg70qc4/9/, if I set it to initial the problem is still there (and you should never set it to initial)

Comment: If you're not annoyed with the text being wrapped/hidden under the input borders then OK!

Comment: This is not a problem for me since it's easly fixed (like setting line-height to 1.1).

Answer (score 0):

if the height of the input is auto, and its height is only comprised by the size of the font-size, i mean, without padding and border, letting the font-size be Xpx, the height of the input will always be slighter bigger,
the reason for that is to accommodate the "leg" of letters like "j" and "g".

Try setting font-size to Xpx, height to Xpx, and input "j" or "y" to the input,
there will be a minor crop.

In addition, put height:auto; font-size:Xpx; and line-height:2;
this time the height will be exactly 2 * Xpx, because with the line-height at 2, there will be room to take in the "legs" of the specific letters i mentioned above.

This subject, context, can also be comparable to another one that has to do with that thin space at the bottom of an image with display:inline; inside of a div, this is easier seen if both elements have a border like border:1px solid Crimson; for instance.

Thank you.